# Consuming data from multiple Topics, Aggregate them and process

Tags: api, apache-kafka

We are consuming data from multiple Kafka Topics (Topic One- Employee Basic Details & Topic 2: Having address details) and then consuming an API (/createEmployee) to another system. In order to call /createEmployee API, we need to aggregate data from both the topics first and them call API.
How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Streams can be used to join and aggregate topics, as well as process the aggregate

https://kafka.apache.org/33/documentation/streams/developer-guide/write-streams.html